# Create multiple new DataFrame columns using DataFrame.assign and apply

Tags: pandas

**Question**

How do I create multiple new DataFrame columns using `DataFrame.assign` and `apply`

**Test code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Cat":1,"Dog":2},index=["10/1/21","11/1/21"])
df


       Cat  Dog
10/1/21 1   2
11/1/21 1   2
```

**Function**

```
def catDog (x):
    if x.Cat > x.Dog:
        sound = "Meow"
    if x.Dog > x.Cat:
        sound = "Woof"
    return (sound,sound[0])
```

**Using apply**

```
df2 = df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand')
df2.columns = ["Sound","Letter"]
df2

       Sound    Letter
10/1/21 Woof    W
11/1/21 Woof    W
```

How do I get this desired output using something like `DataFrame.assign` similar to the following

```
       Cat  Dog Sound   Letter
10/1/21 1   2   Woof    W
11/1/21 1   2   Woof    W
```

**What have I tried?**

I can manually assign without function

```
df = df.assign(Sound="Woof")
df = df.assign(Letter="W")
```

but I want to create any number of new columns using something similar to my (toy) `catDog` function.

Comment: you could merge `df` and `df2` using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) or [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Or you could expand the retuned dataframe into the assign, e.g. with `df.assign(**df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand'))`

Comment: Maybe `df[['Sound', Letter']]= df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand')` if I'm understanding correctly and comment out `df2.columns = ["Sound","Letter"]`.  Also `catDog` function could just be `if else` but consider if they will ever be equal and what should be returned in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Cat":1,"Dog":2},index=["10/1/21","11/1/21"])

def catDog (x):
    if x.Cat > x.Dog:
        sound = "Meow"
    else:
        sound = "Woof"
    return (sound,sound[0])

df[['Sound', 'Letter']] = df.apply(catDog, axis=1, result_type='expand')

print(df)

            Cat     Dog     Sound   Letter
10/1/21     1       2       Woof    W
11/1/21     1       2       Woof    W
```

Answer (score 1):

If you patch your fuction `catDog` to return a dict:

```
def catDog (x):
    if x.Cat > x.Dog:
        sound = "Meow"
    if x.Dog > x.Cat:
        sound = "Woof"
    d = {'Sound': sound,
         'Letter': sound[0]}
    return d
```

You can use `join` to merge your new columns:

```
>>> df.join(df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand'))
         Cat  Dog Sound Letter
10/1/21    1    2  Woof      W
11/1/21    1    2  Woof      W


# or
pd.concat([df, df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand')], axis=1)

# or
df.merge(df.apply(catDog,axis=1, result_type='expand'),
         left_index=True, right_index=True)
```