# Assign values to multiple columns using DataFrame.assign()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of strings stored in a pandas dataframe `df`, with column name of text (i.e. `df['text']`).
I have a function `f(text: str) -> (int, int, int)`.
Now, I want to do the following.

```
df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = df['text'].apply(f)
```

How can I create three columns with the three returned values from the function?

The above code gives the error of

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I tried

```
df['a', 'b', 'c'] = df['text'].apply(f)
```

but I get one column with the name of `'a', 'b', 'c'`

NB:

1. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748849/create-multiple-new-dataframe-columns-using-dataframe-assign-and-apply) in SO, but when I use the following solution from there, I again get an error.

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df['text'].apply(f, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

The error is

```
f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type' #(once I remove the axis=1 parameter)
```

2. Note that `df` has other columns as well

Comment: Thinking and I have to write - Really thank you for feedback. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your solutions working. But need test if correct return 3 values in tuple.

Here is alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[1,2,3]})

def f(x):
    return((x,x+1,x-5))

df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = pd.DataFrame(df['text'].apply(f).tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df)
   text  a  b  c
0     1  1  2 -4
1     2  2  3 -3
2     3  3  4 -2
```

Comment: It works, but
1. I get the [following warning](https://ibb.co/LNfxj5Q).
2. Can you give an overview of what is going on, what the `tolist()` and `index=df.index` does.

Comment: @berinaniesh - First warning - before my solution i not some filtering? Like `df = df[df['col'] > 10]` ? If yes, for avoid it use `copy` like `df = df[df['col'] > 10].copy()`

Comment: @berinaniesh - For list of tuples is used `tolist()` function and then for DataFrame with same index values is pass `df.index`. It is necessary, if original dataframe has different indices.